# How can I produce a Kafka message in a SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka

What options to I have to produce a kafka message from inside a SQL Server trigger?

I.e. when I update a row I want to publish a message to a kafka cluster.

The only option I have in mind is to implement a REST proxy and call this from the trigger procedure. Any other approach?

Comment: I would suggest not doing this in a trigger. Instead push this information to a staging table and have a scheduled task pick up the data and do something with it. If you do this directly in your trigger your update statement is going to have to wait until this external process completes.

Answer (score 1):

From the trigger, insert a row into a message queue table.

Have a SQL Agent job run your message publishing routine and update the queue table, either deleting or flagging the row(s) that was sent.